# Getting "Invalid key code" Exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to press <kbd>ESC</kbd> button manually but I am getting `Invalid Key code Exception`.

Can anyone guide me?

Here is my code:

```
public class PressEscapeButton {
    public void Esc(){
        try{
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED);
        } catch(Exception K){
            System.out.println(K.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try my answer mentioned below?

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is the 'Key' itself. Here, `VK_ESCAPE`

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

You can also try

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();
```

Or,

```
YOUR_OBJECT.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```